# read multiple nested json file with python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

im beginner with python.
i want to read this json file data1 like in the attachment.
i have tried to read all columns in the file, but i can only read the 'data' nest. i don't know how to read all the columns in both "data" and "quotes" nest. can you please help me?
Thankyou

[image: data1]

my code:

````
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('C:/JSON_IMPORT/data1.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])
print (df)



**Json file:**


```{"status":
{"timestamp":"2021-03-16T19:27:55.404Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":173,"credit_count":22,"notice":null,"total_count":4368},
"data":[{"id":1,
"name":"Bitcoin",
"symbol":"BTC",
"slug":"bitcoin",
"num_market_pairs":9862,
"date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
"tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channels","coinbase-ventures-portfolio","three-arrows-capital-portfolio","polychain-capital-portfolio"],
"max_supply":21000000,
"circulating_supply":18655725,
"total_supply":18655725,
"platform":null,
"cmc_rank":1,
"last_updated":"2021-03-16T19:26:11.000Z",
"quote":{
    "USD":{
        "price":55643.86231386882,
        "volume_24h":57006039705.56386,
        "percent_change_1h":-0.22948654,
        "percent_change_24h":-0.66133846,
        "percent_change_7d":3.26713607,
        "percent_change_30d":14.24843475,
        "percent_change_60d":54.21680422,
        "percent_change_90d":168.83609047,
        "market_cap":1038076593265.4004,
        "last_updated":"2021-03-16T19:26:11.000Z"}}     
}}
]
````

Comment: Can you share the json file?

Comment: Hi Manas, i added the sample file on the post. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You should use `pd.json_normalize` and concatenate that with the dataframe made from `data['status']`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data['status'],index=[0]), 
           pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data'])], 
           axis=1)
print(df)

# > timestamp   error_code  error_message   elapsed credit_count    notice  total_count id  name    symbol  slug    num_market_pairs    date_added  tags    max_supply  circulating_supply  total_supply    platform    cmc_rank    last_updated    quote.USD.price quote.USD.volume_24h    quote.USD.percent_change_1h quote.USD.percent_change_24h    quote.USD.percent_change_7d quote.USD.percent_change_30d    quote.USD.percent_change_60d    quote.USD.percent_change_90d    quote.USD.market_cap    quote.USD.last_updated
0   2021-03-16T19:27:55.404Z    0   null    173 22  null    4368    1   Bitcoin BTC bitcoin 9862    2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    ['mineable', 'pow', 'sha-256', 'store-of-value', 'state-channels', 'coinbase-ventures-portfolio', 'three-arrows-capital-portfolio', 'polychain-capital-portfolio']  21000000    18655725    18655725    null    1   2021-03-16T19:26:11.000Z    55643.86231386882   57006039705.56386   -0.22948654 -0.66133846 3.26713607  14.24843475 54.21680422 168.83609047    1038076593265.4004  2021-03-16T19:26:11.000Z
```

Comment: thank you very much. i marked your answear as correct